# Simple spring boot webapp doesnt work, whitelabel error page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I try run my simple "hello world" Spring Boot web application, but it doesn't work, I get "Whitelabel error page" all the time.

**My Controller**

```
package com.packt.webapp.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    public String home(Model model){
        String welcome = new String("Witam");
        model.addAttribute("welcome", welcome);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
package com.packt.webapp.controller;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**home.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <span th:text="'Message: ' + ${welcome}"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.packt.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>basket</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried change my project structure, was playing with dependencies, nothing helps. Can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: where is your html template located in your project structure? Also, what url are you accessing that gives you the error page?

Comment: where is your main class=> Application? Main spring boot class only scans parallel classes and inner package annotated classes(default behaviour) without describing path and where is your html templates they should also placed in resource folder. please also post your application.properties file

Comment: @Gregg html is in `src/main/resources/templates/` and i try `localhost:8080/basket`

Comment: @GurinderSPanesar Application is in `src/main/java/com/packt/webapp/controller` with controller class. I tried to put in inside default `src/main/java` folder and nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your home() method is most likely not being registered by spring since there is no @RequestMapping() above the method.

If you want home to be registered to /, you have two options.  You can move the @RequestMapping that is currently at the class level to the home method like so...

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model){
        String welcome = new String("Witam");
        model.addAttribute("welcome", welcome);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Or you can add an addition annotation above the home() method and leave it empty.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping()
    public String home(Model model){
        String welcome = new String("Witam");
        model.addAttribute("welcome", welcome);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comments above, you're accessing the wrong url. Since you've mapped your controller to `/` and you only have the 1 method, you should access it like:

`http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: `There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).`